# AWS for serverless Google Analytics-like tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, serverless, amazon-kinesis-firehose, serverless-architecture

I'm currently brainstorming an idea and trying to figure out what are the missing pieces or a better way to solve this problem.

Assume I have a product that customers can embed on their website. My end goal is to build a dashboard on my website showing relevant analytics (such as page load, click, custom events) to my customer.

I separated this feature into 2 parts:

**collection of data**

We can collect data from 2 sources:

1. Embed of https://my-bucket/$customerId/product.json

   - CloudFront Logs -> S3 -> Kinesis Data Streams ->  Kinesis Data Firehose -> S3
2. Http request POST /collect to collect an event

   - ApiGateway end point -> Lambda -> Kinesis Data Firehose -> S3

**access of data**

My dashboard will be calling `GET /analytics?event=click&from=...&to=...&productId=...`

The first part is straight forward:

- ApiGateWay route -> Lambda

The struggling part: How can I have my Lambda accessing data at the moment stored on S3?

So far, I have evaluated this options:

- **S3 Glue -> Athena**: Athena is not a high availability service. To my understand, some requests could take minutes to execute. I need something that is fast and snappy.
- **Kinesis Data Firehose -> DynamoDB**: It is difficult to filter and sort on DynamoDB. I'm afraid that the high volume of analytics will slow it down and make it unpractical.
- **QuickSight**: It doesn't expose an SQL way to get data
- **Kinesis Analytics**: It doesn't expose an SQL way to get data
- **Amazon OpenSearch Service**: Feels overkill (?)
- **Redshift**: Looking into it next

I'm most probably misnaming what I'm trying to do as I can't seem to find any relevant help to solve this problem I would think must be quite common.

Comment: How quick are you able to filter from the data you have in S3? Why not transform the data you have on S3 into a database (DynamoDB) ultimately and use that as the data-source for your dashboard?

Comment: Somehow I missed this comment! It takes quite some time to filter and Athena does not guarantee it gets done right away (it could potentially wait for minutes - it generally doesn't, but it could.)


We went with another approach: for reading: AWS Api Gateway end point reads from AWS RDS serverless database. For write, we have a collect endpoint to write to the database and we have a consumer on our CloudFront logs that feeds the access logs to a Lambda that then feeds the database